# How to add devices to Device set in Botium Box

Tags: testing, automated-tests, chatbot

I'm setting Botium box Device set, but I can't choose any Devices. I've set my local Selenium Hub in Device providers. My Selenium hub is running in Docker.

I'm trying to follow this guide: https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/32145510/Run+Selenium+Grid+and+Connect+to+Botium+Box

I can't see any devices provided by auto compete, but I can see Firefox and Chrome in Selenium Grid Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser devices connected to your Selenium hub have to be configured in the *resources/LOCALSELENIUM.json* file (file is cached for a few minutes, so after changing wait some minutes or restart server).

The JSON structure is easy, you can find some description in the mentioned document. What's important is that the *capabilities* element is the actual webdriver capabilities configuration.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Google Chrome",
        "value": {
            "type": "DESKTOP",
            "capabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Mozilla Firefox",
        "value": {
            "type": "DESKTOP",
            "capabilities": {
                "browserName": "firefox"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I've checked it inside container. So I've placed file into host folder and now I can choose Firefox and Chrome, but when I try to run test project:Job failed: Error: not found: java. That means Botium is trying to run webdriver locally instead of in Hub?

Comment: this means that for some reason, Botium tries to start it's own selenium server. Is it possible that the WEBDRIVERIO_START_SELENIUM capability is active ?

Comment: Yes it was active. I've swited it off: Chatbots>Connector/Chatbot Technology=Other (Advanced Settings)>WEBDRIVERIO_START_SELENIUM=disable. Thanks!